# Is it possible to pass fake clock to scheduled task in Spring?

Tags: spring, time, cron, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to test scheduled method that runs once a day. Here is xml part

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" scheduler="myScheduler"/>
<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="10" />
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="refillingServiceImpl" method="refill"
                    cron="0 0 21 * * *" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
<task:executor id="myExecutor" pool-size="5"/>
```

Method runs as expected at specified time according to my system time. But all non-scheduled methods that work with date/time in application use shared Clock instance and when I want to set specific time for test - I just change that Clock instance. Before test I'm setting Clock to 20:59:50

```
//June 18, 2020 20:59:50 Local Time (Kiev, GMT +3), Thursday
    long offset = 1592503190 - Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
    TimeUtil.setClock(Clock.offset(Clock.system(TimeUtil.getDefaultZoneId()), Duration.ofSeconds(offset)));
```

, but I don't know how to say scheduler to use this clock but not system. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Create a bean for `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` by passing a fixed clock to it:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("test")
public class TestThreadPoolTaskSchedulerConfig {

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler() {
        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler threadPoolTaskScheduler
            = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setPoolSize(5);
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setThreadNamePrefix("TestThreadPoolTaskScheduler");
        threadPoolTaskScheduler.setClock(getFixedClock());
        return threadPoolTaskScheduler;
    }

    private static Clock getFixedClock() {
        return Clock.fixed(Instant.parse("2023-02-07T05:15:00Z"), ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    }
}
```